# How do I view File Operations when I have closed Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, 15.04

For example, when I am copying a file from my documents folder to an external USB, a small window labelled `File Operations` appears, showing progress etc. However, when I close Nautilus, it disappears and can't be accessed, even if I open Nautilus again. Is there a way that I can reopen it? I don't seem to have experienced this until I upgraded to Vivid.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you should be able to go to the copying window.

Also, when you click on the "file manager" icon, a new file manager window will appear. Click again on the file manager icon and you should see a "window spread". One window is the file operations window.

You even have a third method: press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and you see a window spread of all open windows, including the file operations window.

<kbd>Super</kbd> is the Windows / Ubuntu / Tux key on your keyboard.